# Line numbers of Python f-strings in abstract syntax tree

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree

When I parse source code with the `ast` module, why is the `lineno` attribute of a `Name` inside a `FormattedValue` set to 1, even when the f-string isn't on line 1?

I'm trying to see which lines of the source code are included in a function definition, so I'm walking the abstract syntax tree nodes below the `FunctionDef` node. I collect all the `lineno` attributes into a set, and that tells me which lines are part of the function definition.

However, when [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings) appeared in Python 3.6, they somehow broke this technique. Here's an example of the problem:

```
import ast

code = """\

f'x{y}'
"""

tree = ast.parse(code)

print(ast.dump(tree, include_attributes=True))
```

Here's the output from that script:

```
Module(body=[Expr(value=JoinedStr(values=[Str(s='x', lineno=2, col_offset=0), FormattedValue(value=Name(id='y', ctx=Load(), lineno=1, col_offset=1), conversion=-1, format_spec=None, lineno=2, col_offset=0)], lineno=2, col_offset=0), lineno=2, col_offset=0)])
```

I know that's pretty unreadable, so here's the same output with some extra whitespace:

```
Module(body=[Expr(value=JoinedStr(values=[
    Str(s='x', lineno=2, col_offset=0), 
    FormattedValue(value=Name(id='y',
                              ctx=Load(),
                              lineno=1,
                              col_offset=1),
                   conversion=-1,
                   format_spec=None,
                   lineno=2,
                   col_offset=0)], lineno=2, col_offset=0), lineno=2, col_offset=0)])
```

The only source code was on line 2, so what's with this part of the output?

```
Name(id='y',
     ctx=Load(),
     lineno=1,
     col_offset=1)
```

I thought it might be the line number *within* the string, but when I try this, it still reports `lineno=1`.

```
code = """\

f'''

x{y}'''
"""
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some research, it seems that f-strings are more powerful than I realized. Each set of braces isn't just a dictionary key as in previous versions of Python, it's a complete block of Python code. That means you can write Python expressions in the braces like this:

```
f'x{y + z}'
```

With that understanding, it makes sense that the `lineno` value is the line number *within the braces*, not within the string or within the whole file. To test that theory, I tried this code, and the `lineno` changed to 3.

```
code = """\

f'''x{

y}'''
"""
```

If I just ignore line numbers from `FormattedValue` nodes, my code works again.